# Type assertion works but annotation does not with HTMLElement

Tags: javascript, typescript

This code works:

```
const a = document.getElementById("input1")! as HTMLInputElement
```

However this one throws an error:

```
const a: HTMLInputElement = document.getElementById("input1")!
```

The error reads:

```
Type 'HTMLElement' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLInputElement': accept, align, alt, autocomplete, and 52 more
```

Can anyone explains why please? Does this mean that with type annotation here, I have to manually specify all those properties? And if so, how would I do it?

Comment: getElementById does not and cannot know the type of the found element, so it returns the most generic one, which is HTMLElement

Comment: With a cast? `const a: HTMLInputElement = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("input1")! `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you make a dom query like `document.getElementById("input1")`, the type you get is `HTMLElement | null`. With the help of `!`, you are telling TypeScript to ignore the possibility that it could be `null`. Now the difference between your attempts is that:

- `const a = document.getElementById("input1")! as HTMLInputElement` means store in `a` a `HTMLElement` casted as `HTMLInputElement`. With type inference of TypeScript, `a` would be of type  `HTMLInputElement`.
- `const a: HTMLInputElement = document.getElementById("input1")!` means you are storing in a `HTMLInputElement` variable, a `HTMLElement` value. Thats's why it's yelling at you.